# How to prove this inference in sequent calculus?

Tags: predicate-logic, formal-proofs

I'm using the event-B prover to proove some proof obligations.

I have a relation representing a $table: table \in 1‥n \to \mathbb{N}$.
I know that in a sorted table the following property is true:

$\forall i· i \in 1‥m−1 \implies table(i)\le table(i+1)$

I would like to prove that from this property we can conclude:

$\forall i,j· i \in 1‥m \land j \in 1‥m \land i\le j  \implies table(i)\le table(j)
$
But I don't know how to conclude this in sequent calculus. From my perspective this is something so evident.
Some help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always induction is your friend.

First,
$i < j$
means
$\exists m > 0
\mid
$i+m = j
$.

Therefore,
we want to show that
$\forall j, a(j)\le a(j+1)
\implies
\forall m>0,
a(j) \le a(j+m)
$.

Base case:
this is true for 
$m=1$.

Induction:
Suppose this is true
for $m$.
Then we have
$1 \le k \le m
\implies
a(j) \le a(j+k)
$.
But we also have
$a(j+m)
\le a(j+m+1)
$.
Since
$a(j) \le a(j+m)$,
this implies that
$a(j) \le a(j+m+1)$.
Therefore
$a(j) \le a(j+k)$
is true for
$k = m+1$,
so that
$1 \le k \le m+1
\implies
a(j) \le a(j+k)
$,
which is what we wanted to prove.

Comment: I would have preferred to use only sequent calculus logic and inference rules, but you gave me an idea on how I might solve it. Thnx